# Problem with understanding the lower bound of OPT in Greedy Set Cover approximation algorithm

Tags: algorithms, approximation, set-cover

From what I know of analyzing and designing approximation algorithms, we need to find a lower bound on the optimum (in the case of minimization). For example if our solution is greedy ($SOL_G$) and if we find a lower bound $L_B$ on $OPT$ then $$L_B \leq OPT$$

and if we correctly analyze the following $$SOL_G \leq f . L_B$$ Then we can conclude that $$SOL_G \leq f. OPT$$ where $f$ is the approximation factor of our greedy solution.

*Vijay Vazirani* in his book approximation algorithm on [page 16](https://books.google.com/books?id=EILqAmzKgYIC&pg=PA16&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) proposed the Greedy Set cover and his analysis of the lower bound on the optimum (**Lemma 2.3**). I have problem with understanding this Lemma:

From his convention at the beginning of the book, $OPT$ stands for the optimum solution of the problem instance (not the optimum that is obtained by the approximation algorithm).

At the beginning of the Lemma he says

> In any iteration, the leftover sets of the optimal solution can cover the remaining elements at a cost of at most *OPT*

It is clear because $\sum_{e \in U} price(e) = OPT$. (The price assignment is based on the selection of the sets)

In the next sentence he says

> Therefore, among these
>   sets, there must be one having cost-effectiveness of at most $OPT/|\bar{C}|$ where $\bar{C} = U - C$

and $C$ is the current list of selected sets.

**I can't understand, why is it true? $OPT$ is the optimum of problem instance not the algorithm. Because in the algorithm the price of each set is distributed among its elements, it seems he uses this fact but $OPT$ is not about the algorithm! it is the optimum of problem instance**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume for simplicity that $C = \emptyset$; I'll let you work out the general case. Note that there are at most $|U|$ sets in OPT. Let $OPT = \{O_1,\ldots,O_m\}$, where $m \leq |U|$. We have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{c(O_i)}{|O_i|} \frac{|O_i \setminus (O_1 \cup \cdots \cup O_{i-1})|}{|U|} \leq \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{c(O_i)}{|O_i|} \frac{|O_i|}{|U|} = \frac{OPT}{|U|}.
$$
On the left-hand side we have a weighted average of the quantities $c(O_i)/|O_i|$, so one of them must be at most $OPT/|U|$. The greedy algorithm selects a set $S$ with $c(S)/|S|$ minimal, so in particular
$$
\frac{c(S)}{|S|} \leq \min\left(\frac{c(O_1)}{|O_1|},\ldots,\frac{c(O_m)}{|O_m|}\right) \leq \frac{OPT}{|U|}.
$$

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. For $i=1$ the weighted average is not defined, right? there is no $O_0$. The weighted average is some thing like $$\dfrac{\sum w_i n_i}{\sum n_i}$$ I didn't fully understand the left hand side (weighted average)

Comment: For $i = 1$ it's just $|O_1|$. The weighted average here is $\sum_{i=1}^m w_i p_i$, where $\sum_{i=1}^m p_i = 1$.

Comment: The greedy algorithm selects $S$ with $\dfrac{c(S)}{|S-C|}$ minimal (where $C$ is the current list of sets, in other word the currently covered elements of $U$) not a set with minimum  $\dfrac{c(S)}{|S|}$. So by this fact, how the following can be true?


$$
\frac{c(S)}{|S|} \leq \min\left(\frac{c(O_1)}{|O_1|},\ldots,\frac{c(O_m)}{|O_m|}\right).
$$

Comment: I only consider the case $C = \emptyset$. Once you understand this case, it's not difficult to generalize to arbitrary $C$.